# SQL: delete old record and keep latest record when duplicate

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a small search engine project and I need some help with a SQL query. My table looks like this (example):

```
user_id  |       group_id
---------------------------
1        |        2
2        |        2
2        |        3
3        |        2
```

i want to delete the old records and leave the newest one when the user_id column is duplicated
How should the select query look like?

Comment: are you doing the delete manually on mysql or through a backend language? do you have timestamp field ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Comes to the same thing. But can a user really only be in one group?

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data

Comment: Create unique index by `user_id` (previously - remove all duplicates from the table data) and use REPLACE instead of INSERT.

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter (1) What difference does it make whether he is doing it directly or via a backend language? (2) What difference does it make whether he has a timestamp field? What is your motivation for these questions?